# Improve lookahead regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a date string like this,

```
'2015-09-24T03:45:19-0700 +0530'
```

I am extracting date and time like below

```
match(/[0-9]+:+[0-9]+:[0-9]+(?=.*?-)/) // returns 03:45:19
match(/[0-9]+-+[0-9]+-[0-9]+(?=.*?T)/) // returns 2015-09-24
```

Is there a way to improve the above regex?

**EDIT:**

When I try `new Date('2015-09-24T03:45:19-0700 +0530')` it says invalid date as this is localised date. Thats when i tried Regex to evaluate another approach. Now I settled down with replacing `"T"` with `" "` and using `new Date`. And it works fine.

Comment: Why so complicate things. You can use [((\d{2}:?){3})](https://regex101.com/r/cS8oZ5/1) and [(\d{4}-(\d{2}-?){2})](https://regex101.com/r/cS8oZ5/2)

Comment: It looks fine for time, unless these is a single number in it, like `'2015-09-24T03:5:19-0700 +0530'`

Comment: How about this [[a-z\]((\d{1,2}:?){3})](https://regex101.com/r/cS8oZ5/3)

Comment: IMO you don't need lookahead. `\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}` would find your time.  anyways, what is wrong with momentJs?

Comment: Post your responses as answers please, so that I can accept best solution

Comment: And whoever down voted, do you mind writing an effin reason.

Comment: What is that date string supposed to mean, with `-0700` followed by `+0530`?

Comment: @hwnd Though above answers does the job, I have questioned myself why not replace `"T"` with `" " `  and use `new Date`. i did that and it is working fine. Your solution clears my confusion, I will settle with this solution. Please post it as answer.

Comment: @Mariano Please add answer, using Date is best option in this case, provided the date format will be like shown in the question, regex is overkill here

Comment: @torazaburo It is timezone and seconds I guess. The date is generated by Jenkins and it is time zone specific date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is an overkill here. You can use `substr` and `split`(*Assuming the format of the string will be same*)

1. Remove the milliseconds and timezone from string
2. Split the resulting string by `T`

```js
var str = '2015-09-24T03:45:19-0700 +0530';

var arr = str.substr(0, str.lastIndexOf('-')).split('T');

var date = arr[0],
  time = arr[1];

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Date = ' + date + ' <br />Time = ' + time;
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

---

**EDIT**

`lastIndexOf` will not work for the negative timezones, ex. `-530`. In this case, you can use regex that'll match `-` followed by four digits to split the string.

```js
var str = '2015-09-24T03:45:19-0700 -0530';

var arr = str.split(/-\d{4}/)[0].split('T');
var date = arr[0],
  time = arr[1];

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Date = ' + date + ' <br />Time = ' + time;
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: Ok, does the job :) May be we can improve it using this `'2015-09-24T03:45:19-0700 +0530'.split(/[T-]/)` ?

Comment: @Exception This'll split the date into year, month and day. Has extra overheads of joining them again

Answer (score 2):

You can split on the space, and use `Date.parse()` to obtain the desired result:

```
yourDate = new Date(Date.parse('2015-09-24T03:45:19-0700 +0530'.split(' ')[0]))
```

The `"T"` is correctly interpreted by `Date.parse()`.

You can then use any of the methods for a date.

Comment: It misses the time, Please look at my edit in question